# jTable field depends On text input

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-jtable

I am on project using jTable and php and I am having a problem with jTable option field where the value depend on another text input. There were over 3000 unique items, so it would not be possible for user to select one of 3000 items. So, I put keywords of items to lessen the number of options.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#TableContainer').jtable({
    title: 'Stock Opname',
    paging: true,
    pageSize: 15,
    sorting: true,
    defaultSorting: 'id',
    actions: {
      listAction: '<?php echo base_url();?>beranda/list/<?php echo $date;?>',
      createAction: '<?php echo base_url();?>beranda/create',
      updateAction: '<?php echo base_url();?>beranda/update',
      deleteAction: '<?php echo base_url();?>beranda/delete'
    },
    fields: {
       keywords: {
        title: 'Keywords',
        list:false,
        edit:false
      },
      namaBarang:{
        title: 'Item name',
        list:false,
        edit:false,
        dependsOn: 'keywords', 
        options: function(data){
            return '<?php echo base_url();?>beranda/search/'+data.dependedValues.keywords;
          }
      },
```

I couldn't send the keywords to php. How I fix this? I am so thankful for all comment and answer.